Solving backwards fractional differential equation with transversality condition
Let's take $\alpha\in(0,1)$ and $f,g\colon[0,T]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ good enough functions. When using the chain rule in fractional calculus in the context of fractional optimal control
$$
\int_0^T  g(t)\;^C_0 D_t^\alpha f(t)\;dt=\left[f(t)\; _t I_T^{1-\alpha}g(t) \right]_{t=0}^T+\int_0^T f(t)\; _t^{RL}D_T^\alpha g(t) \;dt
$$
where $^C_0 D_t^\alpha={_0 I^{1-\alpha}_t}\frac{d}{dt}$ is the Caputo derivative, $^{RL}_0 D_t^\alpha=\frac{d}{dt}{_0 I^{1-\alpha}_t}$ is the Riemann-Liouville derivative and $_0 I^\alpha_t f(t)=\frac{t^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\ast f(t)$ is a convolution operator in $[0,T]$ called the Riemann-Liouville fractional integral, one often wants to enforce the condition
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow T}\; {_t I_T^{1-\alpha}g(t)} = 0
$$
to delete the first term in the right-hand side of the chain rule, that condition is not equivalent to $g(T)=0$, a counterexample can be seen in https://doi.org/10.1177/10775463211031071 Counterexample 2. My question is
How would someone impose the terminal condition in this backwards fractional differential equation?
$$ _t^{RL}D_T^\alpha g(t)=Ag(t)+y(t),\qquad\lim_{t\rightarrow T}\; {_t I_T^{1-\alpha}g(t)} = 0$$
This is crucial to solve fractional optimal control problems but I have not seen a single paper implementing this.
EDIT: to go from left-fractional operator to right-fractional operator there is some kind of duality, essentially just
$$_0 D_{T-t}^\alpha f(T-t)=\pm{_t D_T^\alpha f(t)}$$
I don't have a good rule for the signs but this would just change the sign of $A$ and $y(t)$, the core question remains the same.
